# Python Dictionary & character counting

Tags: python, dictionary, character

I need a dictionary that reads a file (.txt file) and produces a count of every character in that file - letters, numbers, punctuation etc. I'm still pretty new to programming, and have seen how to create dictionaries and give it entries, but I am hitting a block when it comes to having a dictionary which gives a count of all characters in a file. I assume it is within a for loop, but I am unsure. Any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, `result = __import__('collections').Counter(open('myfile.txt').read())`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I apologize if it came off as me trying to get someone else to do work - I was hoping there would be a source or a link to a source where I could get a similar example of what I need, and use that as a starting point. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate on the solution by @TigerhawkT3;

```
import collections

myfile = 'data.txt'
with open(myfile) as f:
    result = dict(collections.Counter(f.read()))

print(result)
```

The `dict` function can be left out and is only needed if you really need `result` to be a dictionary (otherwise it will be a Counter object which is a subclass of a dictionary).